# How to make an Array Accessible from instantiation in main class? Accessible to all classes in same class

Tags: java, arrays

I want to run a method that returns an `array`. Code such as this:

```
public static int[] getArray() {        
    int square[] = new int[5];
    int input = 0;

    System.out.println("Input a valid integer from 1-49");
    System.out.println("for array input please \\(^-^)/");
    System.out.println("Remember (^_'), don't repeat numbers");

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(
            "Please input the integer for position " + (i + 1) + " of the array");
        input = reader.nextInt();
        square[i] = input;
    }

    return square;
}
```

I have researched that you can make a variable like so `int[] data = getArray();`
How would I make it so that data can be accessible to other methods in the same class so I could do something like

```
public static int linearSearch(data) {
}
```

without having to constantly be re-entering the values for the array?

Comment: You can declare a private static int[] data; in the class and then instead of saying return square you just say data = square. The array would be accessible anywhere within the class

Comment: You can not do that. In method declaration you would need to give the datatype of variable u provided. On the other hand if you need to access the variable/array in the same class use static or use `this` to refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare i your array like this:

```
public YourClass {
    public static int[] square = new int[5];

}
```

This way you can access this array from any other class and it will remain with the exact array (that's what static for). Example:

From Class1 - `YourClass.square`
From Class2 - `YourClass.square`
Both are the same array instance

Comment: This isn't what he is asking i guess. OP as i guess needs to know that can we provide a signature like he gave of LinearSearch with providing parameter data without mentioning data type.

Comment: @VivekSingh I think that this is exactly OP is looking for, as he don't want `constantly be re-entering the values for the array` from the console.

Comment: I'm putting the switch cases I have in the main class, I currently had them in a separate method. This should fix the problem of constantly re-calling the method. I'll add a while statement to keep the switches constantly reappearing for input. Thanks for the suggestions - complete newb.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out to introduce private variable of `int[]` and provide a lazy initialization for it, something like this:

```
class aClass {
    int[] data; // default to the null

    private int[] getArray() {
         if (data == null) {
             // your console logic for initialization
         }
         return data;
    }

    public static int linearSearch() {
         int[] localData = getArray();
    }
}
```

But in this case you can change the contents of `data` field in your methods across the class.

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently toying around with this as it's due in about 12 hours for class.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done two ways:
- Either declaring the variable as class-level variable 
- Or declaring it as local variable inside main method

`public class ReturnIntArraysSO {`

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] data = getArray();
    for(int i : data){
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
    linearSearch(data);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 */
public static int[] getArray() {
    int square[] = new int[5];
    int input = 0;

    System.out.println("Input a valid integer from 1-49");
    System.out.println("for array input please \\(^-^)/");
    System.out.println("Remember (^_'), don't repeat numbers");

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please input the integer for position "
                + (i + 1) + " of the array");
        input = reader.nextInt();
        square[i] = input;
    }
    return square;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param data
 * @return
 */
public static void linearSearch(int[] data) {

    for(int a : data){
        if(a == 5){
            System.out.println("\nFound 5!!");              
        }
    }
}
```

}